# Illustrator: Gradient with thicker stop lines

Tags: adobe-photoshop, adobe-illustrator, gradient

I just want to create a simple gradient from 1 color to another - the only difference is, is that I don't want a smooth gradient. I want a gradient with those fancy thicker than normal stop lines, where you can see that it's still a gradient but you see the 'not smooth' transition to the end color. I don't really know how to explain - so I've attached a link to a picture that goes from light gray to darker gray. Is it done with a setting or with double gradient overlaying each other?
What's the best practice for this? and how can I reproduce this effect in Illustrator, mind as well tell me how to do it in Photoshop please :)

[image with gradient background](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B9My50lYp8SEZV9sUHpONEF6cTg)

Comment: Are you talking about the diagonal "banding" that goes across the image producing about 20-30 "bands"?

Comment: Yes that's the one

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using Photoshop, you could switch to Indexed colour mode, and reduce the number of colours to a low number like 17 or so, ensure dithering is set to none, then switch back to RGB mode.

[image]

If you are using Illustrator, you could simply edit the gradient, by adding more stops, and adjusting the midpoint of each stop.

[image]

Comment: Thanks! I was able to reproduce it in Illustrator. Also tried it in Photoshop, but between every stop/band - I get noise, it's not a straight line. Same settings as you posted, but when looking at your image, it has the same.

Comment: @mXX Yeah, but I suppose you could try making a stepped gradient in Photoshop too.